# .net core 3.1 (React) app does not work after deployment

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I published an app which works perfectly, when I start it directly from the publish folder.
but after deploying it to IIS server through IIS Manager, it gives this error:

> InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the create-react-app server was listening for requests. The error output was: npm ERR! code ENOENT

tried many fixes like:

- deleting node_modules,
- deleting package-lock.json,
- then running `npm install`, re-deployement..
- tried npm run build.... no errors.

no luck yet, full error screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: An identical issue [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/765684/34the-npm-script-39start39-exited-without-indicati.html). Hope it helps.

Comment: did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like the issue was, after deployment, app was still set to development mode..

found out it was a problem inside web.config, so I **removed this line** in my **web.config**

```
<environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
```

Answer (score 0):

another more of a forced solution is to put a line under **startup.cs** => Configure Method

```
env.EnvironmentName = "Production";
```